# Android: Send e-mail with attachment automatically in the background

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-service, email-attachments

I am making an app that allows the user to take a picture and send it automatically via email to the email he chooses. So far I was able to take a picture and store in the SD card. Now I only need functions that get the picture from the folder (/sdcard/Pictures/PhotoSender/) and send automatically to the e-mail the user has requested. How can I do this?

I have the picture in that folder. I just need some functions to generate the e-mail, put the picture (.jpg) as an attachment and send (all this on background). When the e-mail gets totally sent, a toast should pop up saying "Upload Done". Meanwhile the user should be free to take more pictures, so the uploading requests should be put on a queue. The user shouldn't login with his e-mail account to send. If needed, I can create an e-mail account for my app to be the "sender". Please help me!

Comment: please show what have you done.

Answer (score 13):

Below is a complete class that supports sending emails with attachments in Android

And here is a utility function to send mail with attachment where the attachment in your case is simply the picture(s) file complete path

```
public static boolean sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject,                                          
                               String message,String[] attachements) throws Exception {     
    Mail mail = new Mail();
    if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
        mail.setSubject(subject);
    } else {
        mail.setSubject("Subject");
    }

    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
        mail.setBody(message);
    } else {
        mail.setBody("Message");
    }

    mail.setTo(new String[] {to});

    if (attachements != null) {
        for (String attachement : attachements) {       
            mail.addAttachment(attachement);
        }
    }
    return mail.send();
}
```

Here is the complete `Mail` class that is used in the above function

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String user;
private String password;

private String[] to;
private String from;

private String port;
private String sport;

private String host;

private String subject;
private String body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart multipart;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String[] getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String[] to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Multipart getMultipart() {
    return multipart;
}

public void setMultipart(Multipart multipart) {
    this.multipart = multipart;
}

public Mail() {
    host = "smtp.googlemail.com"; // default smtp server
    port = "465"; // default smtp port
    sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    user = ""; // username
    password = ""; // password
    from = ""; // email sent from
    subject = ""; // email subject
    body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    this.user = user;
    password = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!user.equals("") && !password.equals("") && to.length > 0
            && !from.equals("") && !subject.equals("") && !body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(body);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(new File(filename).getName());

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this.body = _body;
}
}
```

*Note*:

- You will need `activiation.jar` and `mail.jar` in your classpath i.e. JavaMail API
- The code should run from `AsynchTask` or dedicated `Thread`

Comment: mark his question as a correct answer if it is  @user2155460

Comment: how to get the password of the account created in android from this solution ?

Comment: Not working for me. Depends from Android version?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your device of emualtor has a email application, the below code can be used to sent a mail. You can use any email application installed on your emualtor or device be it yahoomail or google. If you want tp run the same in background use a service.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
//i.setType("text/plain"); //use this line for testing in the emulator  
i.setType("message/rfc822") ; // use from live device
i.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");//sending email via gmail
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject goes here");  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"body goes here");  
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: But that's the problem. If I use this, the user will have to select which application will he use to send the e-mail. For instance, if he uses Hotmail, he will have to log-in using his account. The user should just hit the button "send" in my app and not worry about a thing more. The e-mail would be automatically created and sent, which does not occur if we use this intent =(

Comment: check the dieted answer. But it requires user to login. If you want just sent email by clicking a button you have provide login authentication programatically. The link provided by Mehul Joisar is good for that purpose.