# Sending an e-mail without using the built-in app

Tags: android, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, stack-overflow

I need to send an e-mail with attachments automatically without user input. I previously read these 2 answers.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

[Android: Send e-mail with attachment automatically in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331491/android-send-e-mail-with-attachment-automatically-in-the-background?lq=1).

But now I don't receive any e-mail and I already enabled the less secure apps in gmail. Here's my code :

```
public class Mail {
private String mailhost;
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;
private String serverport;

public void main(String user, String password, String subject, String body){


    sendFromGMail(user, password, subject,body);
}

private void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String subject, String body){
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        InternetAddress adressTo = new InternetAddress(from);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, adressTo);

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch(MessagingException e){
        Log.e("Not Sent", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

}

And this is how I use it :

```
 try {
            Mail mail = new Mail();
            mail.main(gmailusername, gmailpassword, "Test", "Test2");
            this.publishProgress("Email Sent");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            this.publishProgress("Email not sent");
        }
```

Edit : I don't want to use the built-in app as the title suggested. Just wanted to make it clear.

Java debug :

```
08-12 15:08:41.152  24062-24340/com.documax.cardreader I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
08-12 15:08:41.162  24062-24340/com.documax.cardreader I/System.out﹕ DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
08-12 15:08:41.162  24062-24340/com.documax.cardreader I/System.out﹕ DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
08-12 15:08:41.162  24062-24340/com.documax.cardreader I/System.out﹕ DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
```

Comment: and those errors are...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Comment: @Nouman Ghaffar Did you read my question ? I already read this and it's not what I'm looking for. Not entirely.

Comment: @ChristopheRoberge: Can we use javaMail API to receive the email? I am making a app. to block email. DO you think it is possible with JavaMail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), including getting rid of the Authenticator.

Get rid of the call to super() in your constructor, you don't need it.

Also, get rid of the ByteArrayDataSource class.  You don't need your own since it [comes with JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).  Plus, your program isn't even using it.

If it still doesn't work, update your post with your new code and new failure details.

Comment: Changed it for my new actual code. Got rid of the other one. This is the one I'm using without the attachments just to get it working. Now, it doesn't crash or throws any error but still, I'm not getting any e-mails and I enabled the less secure app in gmail.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: You're using an ancient version of JavaMail.  [Upgrade to 1.5.4](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).